# App crashes when insert new data with ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

This the code:

For `insert` of `ContentProvider` :

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {

    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case DOG:
            insertDog(uri, contentValues);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported for " + uri);
    }
}

private Uri insertDog(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long id = db.insert(DogEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (id == -1) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to insert row for " + uri);
        return null;
    }
    return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
}
```

This is where I insert data:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DogEntry.NAME, "Doggy");
    values.put(DogEntry.BREED, "Dingo");
    values.put(DogEntry.GENDER, DogEntry.GENDER_MALE);
    values.put(DogEntry.WEIGHT, 15);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(DogEntry.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

Note: All constants are defined in a contract class.

Comment: "App crashes" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @CommonsWare ,It says Insertion is not supported for the URI. The URI is 300% correct. So what?

Comment: have you run once and change your db schema in that case you need to reinstall your app.

Comment: @DeepNaik The data actually go into the database but it just crashes. When I reopen the app, the data is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget return:

```
...
case DOG:
     return insertDog(uri, contentValues);
```

Explanations: switch goes through all cases and default at the end. We should call break or return in case statements.